# Using $timeout within my app

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I'm using the $timeout service and I'm wondering why my 'mainCtrl.date.raw' variable won't update every second. Any ideas?

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$timeout',function($timeout){
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.date = {};
    $timeout(function(){
        mainCtrl.date.raw = new Date();   
    }, 1000);
}]);
```

Comment: `$timeout` only fires once. You want [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) for recurring functions

Comment: because the cyclic run is provided by $interval. $timeout is only used for delayed run.

Comment: Sorry wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$interval` instead, since `$timeout` will fire the function once when the timer finishes, and `$interval` will fire the function when the counter finishes, and it will start again with the counter, until you clear it.

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$interval',function($interval){
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.date = {};
    $interval(function(){
        mainCtrl.date.raw = new Date();   
    }, 1000);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$timeout` will fire only once, after the timer as reached to an end.
If yo uwant to run a function every n milliseconds, use `$interval`

```js
var app = angular.module('App', [])
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $interval){
    $scope.date = {};
  
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.date.raw = new Date();   
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{date.raw | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}
</body>
```